# Views and sorting by label

Tags: 7, views

In my content type field, I have a select list of current users on the system.  I want to create a page that lists all these usernames in a table.  The key is the user id (uid).  The label is their username.  When sorting in Views, it sorts by the key (uid number).  I want it to sort by the label (username).  Is there a way to do this with Views?  Keep in mind that the user list is all dynamically generated so manually reordering is not an option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal is not powerful enough for this.  Had to write my own module and my own SQL query to get it ordered the way I want.  Maybe in Drupal 8 this feature will be available.